# Spawn person with camera and camera follow him in networked a-frame

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, aframe-networked

My person is moving perfectly without a networked a-frame. But when I'm using a networked a-frame camera is not following the person, It's coming a little bit far from a camera. I want that my camera follows the person.

This is the asset I'm using for the person.

```
<a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="person" src="./person/scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>
```

This is the template i'm using to add a person in the networked scene for multi-user.

```
 <template id="person_template">
        <a-entity
          id="model"
          gltf-model="#person"
          animation-mixer="clip: Rig|man_idle;"
          scale="0.02 0.02 0.02"
          movement-controls="constrainToNavMesh: true"
        >
        </a-entity>
  </template>
```

This is the networked scene I'm using.

```
<a-entity
        id="rig"
        position="-5 0.2 1"
        rotation="0 180 0"
        movement-controls="speed:0.15; constrainToNavMesh: true;"
      >
    <a-entity camera="active:true" position="0 2 0" look-controls>
        <a-entity
            id="player"
            networked="template:#person_template;attachTemplateToLocal:false;"
            movement-controls="speed:0.15; constrainToNavMesh: true;"
            look-controls
            wasd-controls="acceleration:15"
          >
        </a-entity>
    </a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

Comment: You are using tree times the movement controls and two times the look controls One. Maybe this mess things up ? ( usually we use only one of each)

Comment: Oh I'll see this thing.